# Autocomplete values using array

Tags: javascript, json, tabulator

Is it possible to use two arrays to insert data into values rather then hard coding the names of the users in tabulator.

One array would hold the username while the other would hold the actual name of the user.

```
{title:"Approver", field:"Approver", editor:"autocomplete", editorParams:
      {
    values:{
        "jd1":"John Doe",
        "mm12":"Marty McFly",
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To what purpose? What exactly do you want to do? What problem do you have? Please explaint a little bit more so that other users can help you

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to explain better. I want to use two arrays, one that holds the Username and another that holds the actual Name. So in the code snippet above, in values, I would like to have the both arrays read into it. Something like `values: {arrayUsername:arrayName}` I'm just not sure how  to go about it

Comment: If I underestood well, you want an array including `jd1` and `mm12` and another array including `John Doe` and `Marty McFly`. Am I right?

Comment: Yes that is correct!

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: JavaScript, sorry I should have stated that in the issue. Also I should mention that I am using tabulator to create the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Object.keys(values)` and `Object.values(values)` to obtain `username` and `fullname` as two arrays, respectively.